# Overwrite data-dojo-props for title attribute in dijit/TitlePane

Tags: properties, dojo, positioning, title, pane

I have created a TitlePane and wish to load data dynamically from a get method into the Title property. As of the current this all works. However, now when the data is loaded (4 separate types), its all getting mushed together. I wish to divide this received data evenly (25%) across the title.

For example:

```
<div id="tp2" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'I'm a TitlePane        
Too'">
Click arrow to close me.
</div>
```

In this example the title is set to "I'm a TitlePane Too".

I wish to change the title so that each of the four words is evenly distributed across the title section of the pane. However there are no extra properties for doing this sort of thing.

Comment: You need to extend titlepane or write your own widget.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "set" method to set the new title.
E.g:-

```
<div id="tp2" data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title: 'I'm a TitlePane        
Too'">
Click arrow to close me.
</div> 

//For this above example, title is replaced as follows in JS
dijit.byId('tp2').set('title','New title');
```

**Update**: If this title pane is created dynamically without an ID, then get the widget object using the css query.

```
dijit.getEnclosingWidget(dojo.query(".dijitTitlePane")[0]).set('title','New title');
```

`dojo.query(".dijitTitlePane")` => will give array of all titlepane domNodes. From this chose the one you need. I chose at "0"th index i.e. 1st title pane node in the page.
Then I get the widget object of that domNode and then set the title.

Comment: So actually what I used as an example is not how I did it. My title pane is created dynamically in a js file when a get request comes through. so my goes something like this                                var newPane = new TitlePane({      id : idName,                                                     title: Jdata[index].PatientName,      open: false
      }).placeAt(self.roundREC, "last");                                                 so its placed at the bottom of a div thats in html file. so there is no specific id that i can use...

Comment: So, in your JS code, you are setting the id as "idName". So, you have the id :) Use that to get the widget. Else you can use a css selector query --> dijit.getEnclosingWidget(dojo.query(".dijitTitlePane")[0]).set('title','New title');

Comment: So this only gives me reference to the title, but I need to know how to be able to put the title data into the four columns so they are evenly spaced.